# Failable map in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, reactive-cocoa, rxjs

I'm from iOS land where I've used [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) extensively. In RAC, there is `tryMap` operator which `sendError` when the `map`ing operation fails.

Is there an equivalent in Rx.JS? I can mimic the similar behavior using `flatMap` and another `Observable` but that certainly seems like an overkill.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the mapping fail? Do you mean it throws an exception and you want to handle that downstream?

Comment: @paulpdaniels It simply wraps the result of the `map` operation in a kind of `enum` of success with value and failure with error and the operator `tryMap` parses it and handle accordingly. It really isn't unlike `flatMap` and another `Observable` in principle but it is much more concise.

Comment: @paulpdaniels yes it throws and propagates error when the enum contains failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want it to *not* end the stream when a mapping operation fails?  I don't think RxJS it built in, but fairly easy to write.  You just need to catch the error and have `tryMap` basically return an `Either` type of construct that is either an error or the mapping result:

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.tryMap = function(selector) {
  var mapSelector = function(value, index, obs) {
    try {
      return {
        value: selector(value, index, obs)
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        error: e
      };
    }
  };
  return this.map(mapSelector);
};

// Usage:
Rx.Observable
  .of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .tryMap(function(v) {
    if ((v % 2) === 1) {
      throw new Error("odd numbers are evil");
    }

    return v / 2;
  })
  .subscribe(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      console.log("error: " + result.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log("result: " + result.value);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/master/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: This makes sense. But then what if I _do_ want the stream to end when mapping fails? The behaviour of `tryMap` is to end stream & deliver `Error` to `subscribeOnError`. Just a wild guess, does RxJS handles `throw new Error()` inside operator block automatically and propagates it?

Comment: Just verified it does indeed handle it gracefully. Never thought this'd be possible coming from non-exception-throwing language. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Brandon's answer explains a nice way to capture error and pass it down through `onNext` stream.

My original question was to simply end the stream and propagate `Error`, which is apparently very nicely implemented in RxJS by simply `throw`ing an exception inside the `map` operation block. I'm guessing RxJS wraps the entire operations in `try {} catch {}` block and handle exceptions gracefully by sending it down `Error` stream.

I'm writing this as a reference for people coming from ReactiveCocoa whose current implementation doesn't allow to `throw` simply due to the limitation of `Swift` language of not allowing exceptions, which is fixed in Swift 2.

```
Observable.just(1)
  .map(num => { if (num == 1) { throw new Error('error') } return num; })
  .subscribeOnError(console.log) // prints 'error'
```